# Discard and print other lines in C sharp

Tags: c#

appGUID: `643d4128-1484-4aa1-8c17-38ae3b0cf974`

appGUID: `3974af88-1fb1-4ba7-84b9-59aa00c707bb`

I want my program to discard lines that contains some specific values for "appGUID" as in above.

My Code is here :

```
IEnumerable<string> textLines
        = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Unique_Express\", "*.*")
                   .Select(filePath => File.ReadLines(filePath))
                   .SelectMany(line => line)
                   .Where(line => !line.Contains("appGUID: "))
                   .ToList();
```

Comment: these appGUID: <32-digit> string should be discarded.

Comment: Is that the *complete* content of the lines to be discarded? Do you have a collection of these values to be discarded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to check if the `line` contains a specific string by matching the appropriate pattern. The following code will match all lines that do not contain any matches for the expression `appGUID:` followed by a string in the form of a GUID:

```
IEnumerable<string> textLines = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\karansha\Desktop\Unique_Express\", "*.*")
    .Select(filePath => File.ReadLines(filePath))
    .SelectMany(line => line)
    .Where(line => 
        Regex.Matches(line, 
            "appGUID: [0-9a-fA-F]{8}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{4}-[0-9a-fA-F]{12}").Count == 0)
    .ToList();
    }
```